# z3 has unresolved symbols on Ubuntu 12.04 x86

Tags: ubuntu, compilation, symbols, z3

Z3 intalled from `http://research.microsoft.com/projects/z3/z3-3.2.tar.gz` on Ubuntu 12.04 x86 seems to have unresolved symbols. Running a simple application, that uses z3 bindings results in:

`./app: symbol lookup error: /PATH/TO/z3/lib/libz3.so: undefined symbol: GOMP_critical_name_start`

Answer (score 2):

3.2 is an outdated version, you probably want to see the site on codeplex:  http://z3.codeplex.com/

Here are the compilation instructions: http://z3.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#README